# Excel macro crashes after running for a few minutes

Tags: excel, vba

My code runs for about 5min and the goes into recovery error/message. I have posted 3 Call macros but have 40 in the code.

During the macro the cells need to calculate and I tried a time delay to help but no good.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()

    If Range("$be8").Value = 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Call Macro1
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
    If Range("$bf8").Value = 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Call Macro2
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
    If Range("$bg8").Value = 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Call Macro3
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If


 Sub Macro1()
'
'

     Macro1 Macro
    '

    '

            Sheets("Calc. 1").Select
            Rows("11:11").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
            Rows("7:7").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Rows("11:11").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Range("B1").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
            Range("B2").Select
            Sheets("Calc.").Select
            Range("A7:Q50002").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("A3").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Calculate
            Range("AZ3").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("BA3").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Range("A1").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
            Range("B1").Select
            Workbooks.Add
            DoEvents
        End Sub


        Sub Macro2()
        '
        ' Macro2 Macro
        '

        '
            Sheets("Calc. 1").Select
            Rows("11:11").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
            Rows("7:7").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Rows("11:11").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Range("B1").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
            Range("B2").Select
            Sheets("Calc.").Select
            Range("A8:Q50002").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("A3").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Calculate
            Range("AZ3").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("BA3").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Range("A1").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
            Range("B1").Select
            Workbooks.Add
            DoEvents
        End Sub

        Sub Macro3()
        '
        ' Macro3 Macro
        '

        '
            Sheets("Calc. 1").Select
            Rows("11:11").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
            Rows("7:7").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Rows("11:11").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Range("B1").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
            Range("B2").Select
            Sheets("Calc.").Select
            Range("A9:Q50002").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("A3").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Calculate
            Range("AZ3").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("BA3").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Range("A1").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
            Range("B1").Select
            Workbooks.Add
            DoEvents
        End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these macro, there will be a simple `VBA` solution if you explain the problem you're trying to solve. :-)

Comment: In some cases within `Worksheet_calculate` you are disabling events and then exiting: there will be no firing of that event handler past that point.  It's not clear if that's what you want/intend.

Comment: I'm assuming you're running a process intense formula or a bunch of formulas on a bunch of cells. Instead of the time delays which just add more unnecessary delays, try adding Application.ScreenUpdating = False at the beginning of Worksheet_calculate() procedure and Application.ScreenUpdating = True at the end of it and see if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is just a big pack of recorded macros, and therefore nearly unreadable, as hinted by Matt Webb in its excellent comment. That being said, I went to do some analysis.

The macros are strictly the same, besides the column of the *Range("A7:Q50002").Select*, which varies from 7 to 9 (and probably up to 46, if you really have 40 of those). Time to make a proper sub with a parameter :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
    If Range("$be8").Value = 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Call Macro(myRow)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
    If Range("$bf8").Value = 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Call Macro(myRow)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
    If Range("$bg8").Value = 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Call Macro(myRow)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
End Sub


 Sub Macro(myRow)
    Sheets("Calc. 1").Rows("11:11").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Rows("7:7").Copy
    Rows("11:11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    'Range("B2").Select
    Sheets("Calc.").Range("A" & CStr(myRow) & ":Q50002").Copy
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Calculate
    Range("AZ3").Copy
    Range("BA3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    'Range("B1").Select
    Workbooks.Add
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

it'still ugly, but now, you just have 1 main procedure instead of 40, and I cleaned a little bit. I also did comment the useless selects.

Next question : what does it do? Seems like it

- inserts the row 11, then copies the row 7 into. That one shall not be problematic.
- Copies a specific cell from another sheet to the current sheet. Well, why not.
- Calculates. Here we have a problem. I have no clue of your calculations, and there very well might be circular things here, or insane amounts of calculations to do. Especially when I see hard-coded values going to the 50000th row... The wolf may hide here. Depends on your worksheet. This is my first suspect.
- Copy another cell in the main sheet. No risk here.
- Add an empty workbook. Without anything. Hum, are you sure? If your 40 values are positive, you dynamically open 40 workbooks, without naming them, or putting any data in them??? This is my second and last suspect.

Now, you have to troubleshoot yourself to know which suspect is guilty. For that, you can add breakpoints on a few strategic lines of the macro, to see what takes time(my bet on the calculate, but I may be wrong). Especially before & after the calculate & the Workbook.add

But ask yourself is everything I listed is useful, especially the calculate part, and especially the workbook.add part. Your macro might very well flood the computer memory with all those workbooks open in memory that are still useless.

Comment: Hi, . A3 - Q50000 is the cells that hold the data. Within this data, blocks of info that i calculate in cells to the right of row q. So there might be 15 rows. Formulas calc. those rows and insert the outcome on the row that is inserted in the Calc1 sheet. because the block can range from 4 - 50 that is where i have the different call code. A range of cells lets it know how big the block is eg BE7 = 4 so BE8 will be a 1 if the block is 4. BD7 =5 so BD8 will be 1. It will then run that appropriate macro to copy and paste the A3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-Q50000 to move to next block.